# Dash is blinking

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, conky, screenlets

I Have installed a screenlet applet and Conky to my PC.

But when I open dash it starting to blink and show through these applets. How do I correct this.

Answer (score 3):

The [Conky FAQ](http://conky.sourceforge.net/faq.html) has a section with two possible workarounds in case *Conky* is flickering - I don't know whether one or other of these would help in the inverse case, but it probably doesn't hurt to find out.

It suggests adding either

```
double_buffer yes
```

or

```
own_window yes
```

to your `.conkyrc` file.

Comment: Thank You very much for your soon reply. sory for my bad English

Comment: I did it. But it doesn't help me, Is there a another way to correct this?